# RDP Equivalent for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a remote access solution (from a machine to the Ubuntu computer) that acts like RDP in Windows, i.e. a user can be logged in on the actual machine, and someone else can be logged in remotely.

I know about XDMCP, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu 10.10 with GDM. I know I can use another desktop manager, but others don't look as nice as GDM (at least ones I have seen).

Is there some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NX

Any of the NX server/client solutions can do what you ask about.  The NX server will spawn a new session for each remote connecting, so it wont disturb other users connections or the person at the terminal.

There are a few servers freenx, neatx, and nomachine's server.  I think everyone uses the same client app from nomachine (available for linux and windows).

Comment: NX is great definitely A++ in my book. I think it also uses less resources.

Comment: It is definitely more network friendly.  Its not sending pictures like VNC and its not raw x protocol messages.  Great for accessing through VPN's.

Comment: Thank you, NX really is great, I'm using freenx and it's working just like I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, Ubuntu comes with a VNC server, [vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino), and client, [vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre), by default.

Since with this approach you can easily attach to an existing session, it is probably the closest thing to RDP on Windows. If you want to be able to start a session remotely with some level of ease, XDMCP is probably the way to go.

Comment: I don't think I was very clear in my question, but when I said "a user can be logged in on the actual machine, and someone else can be logged in remotely', I meant two different users/usernames. VNC wouldn't work for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need vnc.

Comment: Same as my comment on oKtosiTe's response

Answer (score 1):

Why not use kdm or wdm? It's not as if you would spend a lot of time staring at the desktop manager.

If you insist on gdm, there's a mention of an upstream fix in [Ubuntu bug #408417](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/408417), and some workarounds are suggested in
[Ubuntu bug #669670](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/669670).